# Using 19v laptop charger to charge 4S 18650 battery pack

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger, bms

I am manually assembling an 18650 4S battery pack for use with an inverter/ups. My goal is to build a portable inverter based on 18650 batteries (around 20AH capacity) which has the provision for charging the battery pack also. Most of the inverter circuits are either built for 12v lead acid batteries or for 14.4v sealed batteries. These inverter circuits have builtin charging capability. But i could not find a similar circuit for 4S 18650 battery pack. The 3S battery pack is too low and the 4S battery pack is too high for these circuits. I was hoping to get the 4S pack with BMS working with UPS designed for computer systems as their inbuilt batteries are 14.4v but that didn't work as expected. I also tried the 3S pack with the home inverter but that also didn't work. I am summarizing below what i tried to do.

I ordered a  [4S BMS board](https://robu.in/product/4-series-40a-18650-lithium-battery-protection-board-14-8v-16-8v-with-balance-for-drill-motor-lipo-cell-module/) and i am using 4 series 4 parallel 18650 batteries for around 8800 mAH capacity. I charged the 18650 cells individually using a powerbank circuit and then hooked them to the BMS board. I tested the pack with a modern UPS circuit board. When the battery pack was fully charged the UPS constantly beeped and did not turn on the AC output. The most probable cause could be the over voltage protection as the fully charged voltage of 4S pack is over 16 volts. I then used an old UPS circuit board (probably not having such protection) and it worked. After discharging it almost halfway through i tested it again on the modern UPS and it worked fine. However, i tried to charge the pack with both the UPS circuits and connected an ammeter in series to watch the current. But the max current flow i could get was around 100 mA. Again the most probable cause is that the UPS thinks that the battery is fully charged as the voltage of 50% discharged 4S battery pack is more than even the 100% charge of 12v/14v battery used in the UPS. I then tried a [3S BMS board](https://robu.in/product/3-series-40a-18650-lithium-battery-protection-board-11-1v-12-6v-with-balance-for-drill-motor-lipo-cell-module/) and the UPS did start charging it at around 1.5A but while testing the discharging caused under voltage cutoff only after using for a few minutes as the nominal voltage for 3S is around 11v and the UPS cuts off around that voltage for overdischarge protection of 12v/14v batteries. So the 3S pack is out of question. I also tried both on the regular home inverter, designed for 12v battery system, but that too had the above mentioned problems/limitations.

Finally, i tried charging the 4S pack with a 19v laptop charger. I connected an ammeter in series to watch the current. What i observed is that the laptop charger does not feed a constant current to the BMS and only pulses for a brief moment once roughly every second.I thought that the laptop charger is faulty and changed the laptop charger but observed the same behaviour with the second charger. I left the charger on overnight but the charge gained by the battery pack was negligible.

My best guess is that there can only be two reasons for this behaviour. One is that the 19v provided by the laptop charger is too high to charge the 16.8v 4S battery pack and the BMS is causing this "pulsing" behaviour. The BMS is trying to charge the battery and as soon as it discovers that the incoming voltage is 19v it shuts off the charging. Then it tries again after a second or so and the cycle repeats resulting in the the pulsing behaviour. The other reason might be that it is perhaps the default behaviour of the laptop chargers. I might be completely wrong, i don't know.

So my questions are:

1. What is the cause for this "pulsing" behaviour? Is it the default behaviour of laptop chargers?
2. Do i need any other piece of intermediate circuit between the laptop charger and the BMS board to charge the pack from the laptop charger?
3. Is there any specifically designed inverter circuit board for 4S 18650 battery packs with inbuilt charging facility and battery level indication or at least a complete circuit diagram for a DIY?

I hope there is a solution somewhere!

Comment: Some laptop power bricks try to communicate with their laptop and will not work if they are connected to anything else. What you see is the negotiation sequence.

Comment: _"laptop charger does not feed a constant current to"_ It was never designed to. How are you providing constant current to the batteries from your constant current voltage source? Also, schematic please!

Comment: @winny i am not able to provide any current/voltage to the batteries as i do not have any suitable source. That is why i tried to charge them with the laptop charger. Can you please explain why the laptop charger is not designed to do so. I mean even a laptop charger is designed to charge the laptop batteries (which are composed of 18650 batteries). So why can't i charge my battery pack composed of 18650 with it? I'm not an expert in electronics so kindly bear with me.

Comment: @LiorBilia i have so far tried 4 different laptop chargers from 4 different vendors but all have exhibited the same behaviour. If what you are suggesting is the case, is there a way to "trick" the power brick?

Comment: Because there is circuitry inside the laptop to interface the voltage source (laptop charger) to the batteries. I strongly suggest you take two steps back and stop what you are doing before you hurt yourself or anyone else in a lithium-fueled explosion.

Comment: Stop immediately connecting laptop power supply to lithium batteries before something explodes or catches fire. Laptop power supply is nothing but a power supply, it is NOT a charger for anything! The lithium battery charger is inside the laptop. Similarly, USB power supply is a power supply to your mobile phone, and the charging circuitry is in the phone.

Comment: Stop trying to use the wrong tools for the job. To charge a Li-Ion battery, use a charger designed for Li-Ion batteries. To use a system designed for 14.4V batteries, use it with 14.4V batteries. (4 cells of LiFePO4 happen to be about that voltage and would be much less dangerous than the batteries you are using. They still require the correct charging profile, CC/CV/cutoff when I falls to some percentage of the CC value, so you can't just plug them in to the charger of your UPS, but they are closer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is really a what to buy question disguised as how to do a job with the wrong (and dangerous) tools.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your comments and suggestions. Now i can understand that there is a difference between a power supply and a charging circuit and both are needed to effectively charge a battery. Perhaps i didn't know what to ask that is why this sounds like a "what to buy" kind of question. Now that i know what i am looking for, could anyone please point me to a good charging circuit link (for 18650 batteries). I am not asking for a link to buy something, I am just asking for a link to the right circuit board/design/schematic so that i can be sure i am looking at the right tools. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Laptop power supply is a power supply. It is not a charger for lithium batteries. It can not and must not be directly connected to batteries. Most likely what happens is that the 19V output will drop when it is connected to batteries with lower than 19V, and the power supply tries to give as much as current possible to try rising voltage back to 19V, but it may hit overcurrent limit or undervoltage limit and output will shut down, and retry about every second or so.
2. Yes, the actual lithium battery charger circuitry. A BMS is not a charger either.
3. That is kind of what to buy question.

Comment: Thank you @Justme for your detailed explanation of the "pulsating" behaviour, I got it now. Can you please point me in the right direction by providing a link to some resources where i can read more about the design/construction/schematic of a lithium battery charger circuitry? I have tried to google it myself but i'm kind of hitting the wall.